# Passing a function into another function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is similar to this:

```
function foo(array1, fun) {
    var n;
    n = a.length;
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++) {
        fun(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a function called `mult(x)` that I will pass into `foo` when I call it. My question is what do I put in the parameters of my `mult` function when I want to call:

```
foo(some_array, mult(x));
```

Comment: Are `array1` and `a` supposed to refer to the same thing?

Comment: there is going to be two arrays. That function fun should multiply the elements at[i] of the two arrays together. Then add the result with the at[i+1]. I am still trying to figure this out

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/01.html Sums it up.

Answer (score 6):

Just pass in a reference to it (its name only)...

```
foo(some_array, mult);
```

Alternatively, pass in an anonymous function...

```
foo(some_array, function() { ... });
```

The first argument of this function you pass in with will be set to `a[i]` like in the body on your function.

Comment: would mult be something like:  var mult = function mult(x){  }

Comment: @Spence Yep, it can be a function expression or declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten to showcase how you call a function in JS

```
function mult(x){
    //do stuff to x
}

function foo(array1, fun){
    var n = array1.length;
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++) {
        mult(array1[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what happened to the usage of `array1`?